# How to omit empty/null field's before submitting form with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm using formik to handle form state and pass it on to a function that will send a patch request to the API, but when the form is sent all the fields(including empty and or null) fields so the API treats it as an input and overwrites the previous data.

**my formik initialValues:**

```
                enableReinitialize
                initialValues={{
                    firstname: userdata?.firstname ?? "",
                    lastname: userdata?.lastname ?? "",
                    age: userdata?.age ?? "",
                    phone: userdata?.phone ?? "",
                    secondary_phone: userdata?.secondary_phone ?? "",
                    image: null,
                    sex: userdata?.sex ?? "",
                    height: userdata?.height ?? "",
                    wereda: userdata?.wereda ?? "",
                    kebele: userdata?.kebele ?? "",
                    address: userdata?.address ?? "",
                }}
```

in the example above most of the fields will not be null since I am setting the initial data from the server but making this the only guard and putting hope on the user to not clear the input before sending is a big risk, also I cannot send the image URL as a field value to the server since it needs an image file and I don't like the idea of converting the URL to a js File object, so how can I omit all the fields that are "" or null before passing it over to the function that will take care of the API request?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I googled it and found some code, modified it to look like this:

```
     Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
            if (values[key] === '' || values[key] === null) {
                     delete values[key];
              }
            });
```

It iterates trough the object and deletes any that has a value of either "" or null